# how to write values of an array to mysql table inside for each loop?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

i have recived some data via post method i wrote the data to array now how i can write da data to mysql table ? sample of data recive is shown below. i keep getting this error:Error, query failed

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $data = [];
    foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $rowNum) {
        $data[] = explode("::", $_POST['opt'][$rowNum]);
    }
    var_dump($data);

    $sku =$data[$rowNum][0];
    $description =$data[$rowNum][1];
    $location =$data[$rowNum][2];
    $quantitydate =$data[$rowNum][3];

    $link = mysqli_connect("somesite", "****", "*******", "******");
    // Check connection
    if($link === false){
        die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $query ="SELECT * FROM Test WHERE sku = '$sku'";
    $testResult = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die('Error, query failed');    

    if(mysqli_fetch_array($testResult) == NULL){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO test (ID, sku, description, location, quantitydate) VALUES ('$ID','$sku', '$description','$location', '$quantitydate',NOW())";
        if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
            echo "Records added successfully.<br /><br />";
        } else{
            echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
        }

        // close connection
        mysqli_close($link);
    }else
        {
            echo "Record Already Exist<br /><br />";
        }
}
```

output sample:

```
// Output sample (selected row 2 and 4):
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'SKU2' (length=4)
      1 => string 'DESC2' (length=5)
      2 => string 'LOC2' (length=4)
      3 => string 'QUAN2' (length=5)
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'SKU4' (length=4)
      1 => string 'DESC4' (length=5)
      2 => string 'LOC4' (length=4)
      3 => string 'QUAN4' (length=5)
```

Comment: What's the problem? Loop over `$data` and do an `INSERT INTO TABLE` query with the values from each row.

Comment: i edit my post i tried the above but keep getting this error:Error, query failed

Comment: Change `die('Error, query failed')` to `die(mysqli_error($link))` so you see the reason for the failure.

Comment: Why are you passing both `$quantitydate` and `NOW()` in the `INSERT` query? You have more values than columns you're assigning to.

Comment: Where is the `$ID` variable? Is that supposed to be an auto-increment column? You can just leave it out of the `INSERT` and it will be incremented automatically.

Comment: Thanks bamar i fixed most of the problem but only one record get entered into database and the second record is empty !

Comment: Do you have a `foreach` loop like in my answer?

Comment: this is the foreach i use and the sql block of codes is after explode line :=> foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $rowNum) {
            $data[] = explode("::", $_POST['opt'][$rowNum]); // the sql codes after here 
          }

Comment: The problem is with `$data[$rowNum]`. You're not assigning the post data to `$data[$rowNum]`, you're assigning it to `$row[]`, which just uses the next available index in the `$row` array.

Comment: I've updated the answer to do the SQL codes inside the `$_POST['checkbox']` loop. There's no need to assign to `$data[]` in this case.

Comment: so i can just move my block of code inside another for each loop(outside first foreach loop) like this :foreach ($data as $row) { ......} and use $sku =$row[0]; instead of $sku =$data[$rowNum][0]; ?

Comment: That's how I wrote it in the first version of my answer. But you didn't want to do that, so I rewrote the answer to do it like you wanted. Why aren't you looking at my answer and commenting on that?

Comment: thanks a lot finally it worked as it should!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a prepared statement:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT IGNORE INTO tableName (sku, description, location, quantitydate) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssss", $sku, $desc, $location, $quantitydate);
foreach ($_POST['checkbox' as $rowNum) {
    $row = explode('::', $_POST['opt'][$rowNum]);
    $sku = $row[0];
    $description = $row[1];
    $location = $row[2];
    $quantitydate = $row[3];
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    if (mysqli_affected_rows($stmt) == 0) {
        echo "SKU $sku already exists <br/><br/>";
    }
}
```

If you have a unique index on the `sku` column, you don't need to perform the `SELECT` query first. `INSERT IGNORE` will simply ignore the attempt to add a duplicate row, and `mysqli_affected_rows` will return `0` to indicate that nothing was inserted.

Comment: thanks for reply. i have edited my post . i am not familiar with PDO. could you tell me what part is wrong in my above code?